Montgomery Ladder on Weierstrass Curve
I want to use the Montgomery ladder to speed up the process of calculating scalar multiplication. Here I use the Montgomery ladder but on the Weierstrass curve.
In the equation $x^3 + 2x + 9 \bmod 37$ the result is correct.
But why on the curve $x^3 + x + 1 \bmod 463$ the result is wrong? Is there a specific criterion for using the Montgomery ladder on the Weierstrass curve? thank you.

Did you check for all points? The first curve is a prime curve. Montgomery ladder request Montgomery Curve and those are not prime, need at least a factor of 4.

Maybe you are confused with the Joce ladder
